# Is there any subsequence of a funtion sequence converges at every point

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f_n(x)＝\sin{nx}，n＝1,2,…$ be a sequence of functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there a subsequence
$f_{n_j}(x)$ that converges at every point $x \in \mathbb{R}$？

(Note that the subsequence *must not* rely on the point $x$.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that in gernal not true and $sin(nx)$ is a possible counter example (allthough its more tedious to see this than for other counter examples). However, there is convergent subnet.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, any references to get more details？

Comment: Are you interested in sin(nx) or in any sequence?

Comment: This smells like a Baire category-type problem to me.

Comment: Maybe sin(nx) is enough，but I'm also interested in the others.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x)$ be the $n$-th digit in the binary expansion of $x$. If you equipp $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, it is easy to check that $(f_n)_n$ are independent random variables and $\lambda(f_n=0)=\lambda(f_n=1)=1/2$.

Clearly, any subsequence $f_{n_k}$ is again a sequence of independet random variables.

Let $(f_{n_k})_k$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $(f_n)_n$. The strong law of large number implies that there is a set $A \subset [0,1]$ with $\lambda(A)=1$ s.t.
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N f_{n_k}(x) \to 1/2
$$
for all $x \in A$.

Fix $x$: If $(f_{n_k}(x))_k$ converges, then its limit can only be $0$ or $1$. In this case, its Cesaro mean is convergent as well with the same limit. Hence, for all $x \in A$ the $(f_{n_k}(x))_k$ is *not* convergent. Since $A$ has measure 1, it is in particular nonempty. Therefore, $(f_{n_k})_k$ dosn't converge pointwise.

Remark: Since $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, that example shows that compactness doesn't imply sequential compactness.